# perl readdir() on network directory - scalar vs list context and network performance

Tags: perl, network-programming, performance

We have a network share with a large number of files and are going to iterate over all files via perl readdir(). Which is more efficient with network communication (or are they the same)?
1) readdir in list context?
2) readdir in scalar context?

Usually I would avoid the list context to avoid having to store the entire list in memory, but if it's going to hit the share once in list context and many times in scalar context then I'd rather go with the list context.

Thanks!
-Peter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is some code to benchmark the difference:

```
use Benchmark;

my $dir_name = 'a network path';
timethese(-2, {
    scalar => sub {
        opendir(my $dir, $dir_name);
        while(my $entry = readdir($dir)) {
        }
    },
    list => sub {
        opendir(my $dir, $dir_name);
        my @entries = readdir($dir);
    },
});
```

The results were quite similar on my machine/network (WinXP and a distant share), however a bit in favor of `scalar` version.